# How to install aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc on OpenSUSE 15.4

Tags: gcc, arm64, opensuse

I want to install aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc on an OpenSUSE 15.4 system.
What is the command to install this?

I try `zypper install cross-aarch64-gcc7` but the package doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't have the proper repositories enabled. Try running:

```bash
zypper addrepo https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:Factory/standard/openSUSE:Factory.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install cross-aarch64-gcc7
```

This should add the Factory repository and install cross aarch64.

If this doesn't work due to the recent openSUSE Factory changes, try

```bash
rpm -iv http://provo-mirror.opensuse.org/source/tumbleweed/repo/oss/src/cross-aarch64-gcc7-7.5.0%2Br278197-15.2.src.rpm
```